# How to get SQL Server names without connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Work on C#, in one of my application I need to get the SQL Server names. In network I have SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008. For my application I want to get the server names.

```
private string strConnection = @"Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
objConnection.Open();
SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(“xxxxxxx”);
objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
objConnection.Close();
```

If I know `strConnection` then I can use the above syntax. But I don’t know the server name. In my application first I need to know the server name. I need help to get the server names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few options how to find those in code - see:

- [Locate SQL Server instances on the local network](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/locate_sql_servers.aspx) - uses the UDP protocol and sockets to find SQL Server on a LAN
- [Enumerating Instances of SQL Server (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx) - uses ADO.NET and a `SqlDataSourceEnumerator`  to find SQL Servers and returns a `DataTable` with info about them

There are quite a few more ways to find your SQL Servers - do these options work for you??

Comment: +1 The ADO.NET utility class is very nice. I was thinking of nmaping and what not. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Scan network for SQL Server instances](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/scan-network-for-sql-server-instances) to get some ideas about SQL Ping

Answer (score 0):

You can use Use [SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoapplication.enumavailablesqlservers.aspx) method to Enumerate a list of available instances of SQL Server.

Comment: Works - but it requires SMO to be present which means a) either install the SQL Server Client Tools with SMO, or b) install SMO separately.